# What is the best way to inject configuration settings into Javascript in an MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

What is the best way to inject configuration settings into Javascript in an MVC app?
I've seen how it is done using ASP.NET webforms, but not sure how to do this with MVC.

```
@using System.Configuration
...

var checkTimer = @ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CheckTimer"];
```

In Web.config:

```
<appSettings>        
    <!-- Polling timer to check for alerts -->
    <add key="CheckTimer" value="10000"/>    
</appSettings>
```

But in my rendered output I just get the following:

```
var checkTimer = ;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var checkTimer = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CheckTimer"]));
```

Comment: I've tried that but it is still null.  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Count returns 0 though. I have the settings in a web.config in a MVC app...?

Comment: @jaffa, the fact that it is null means that the key is not present in the web.config of the Application under this key (the key is case sensitive).

Comment: what an idiot, I was looking at web.config in the \views folder! Why there needs to be a separate config in there I don't know;) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Javascript serializer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it is not too fancy , you can have a hidden variable and then access it in javascript.